# WordPress and GET

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I'm having form and page(Template Page) in WP. Through form, I want send values GET, then the page create query.

form:

```
<form id="homepage_form" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="p" value="48" />
    <input class="first" type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="location"/>
    <select name="category">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>Kategori</option>
    </select>
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

First Question. Do I need send id page in form?(input type="hidden" name="p" value="48"). Maybe is other method.

Second Question. When I sent this form, I saw "page_id_48/?location=asdasd". WP stolen second GET (name).

Now I know... I don't like forms in WP or I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WP can't to send get 'name'

`<input class="first" type="text" name="name" />`
<- bad

`<input class="first" type="text" name="notname" />` <- ok

Answer (score 0):

you need the attribute value , in order to GET it.

```
<input class="first" type="text" name="name" value="something" />
```

Comment: And? I don't understand. How can it help me?

Comment: If you are passing something in get you need attribue value="something"  ,